# Batch - For /F with IF/File/Comparison

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, comparison

Dears,

I'm hoping you can help me, because I lost my faith.
Let me show you what I have done, and then explain what I need to achive.

```
@echo off    
echo "Which Site do you want to check?"
set /p ans="Site: "
echo.

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%A IN (animals.csv) DO if %%A==%ANS% (ping %%B AND ping %%C)
echo.
pause
echo.
cls
goto menu
```

1. User should put something animal name which will be stored in ANS variable.
2. Script should check in animals.csv what IP adresses are assigned for that animal.
3. After matching, script should ping IP adresses in next columns, so user could see results.
   PS: All both files are in the same folder.

Problem is that animals.txt has 3 columns and a lot of records.
I was able make script work till point of comparing variables, then I stopped working.

Let's say that animals file looks like that:

```
cat,111.111.111.111,122.122.122.122 
dog,222.222.222.222,233.233.233.233 
horse,333.333.333.333,344.344.344.344
```

Help me, because I stuck and I have no damn clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your script works, when you replace `AND` with `&` (see [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html))

But let me suggest a slightly different logic:

```
@echo off    
echo "Which Site do you want to check?"
set /p ans="Site: "
echo.

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%A IN ('type animals.csv^|findstr /b "%ans%,"') DO (
  ping %%B
  ping %%C
)
echo.
pause
```

`findstr` parameter `/b` means "string should start with" - prevents `maddog` to be recognized as `dog`.
The trailing comma in the searchstring prevents `catfish` to be recognized as `cat`.
You might want to add `/i` to make the search case-insensitive (`cat` and `Cat` will be recognized).

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOO much, I was working on something for hours, so my brain decided to go for a walk :)